# Avoid repetition in mapping to Union type cases

Tags: f#

I have a 3rd party library from which I can get `IReadOnlyList<IEvent>` whereas `IEvent` as this signature:

```cs
public interface IEvent {
  object Data { get; }
}
```

The library also provides a generic class `Event<T>` which has this signature:

```cs
public class Event<T> : IEvent {
   public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have a union type like this:

```ml
type AccountCreated =
  { Owner: string
    AccountId: Guid
    CreatedAt: DateTimeOffset
    StartingBalance: decimal }

type AccountDebited =
  { To: Guid
    From: Guid
    Description: string
    Time: DateTimeOffset
    Amount: decimal }

type AccountCredited =
  { To: Guid
    From: Guid
    Description: string
    Time: DateTimeOffset
    Amount: decimal }

type AccountEvent =
  | AccountCreated of AccountCreated
  | AccountCredited of AccountCredited
  | AccountDebited of AccountDebited
```

I have a mapping function using pattern matching and I'm asking myself if this could be implemented in a more generic manner to avoid repetition:

```ml
let map (input: Events.IEvent): AccountEvent =
  match input with
  | :? (Events.Event<AccountCreated>) as event ->
    AccountCreated event.Data
  | :? (Events.Event<AccountCredited>) as event ->
      AccountCredited event.Data
  | :? (Events.Event<AccountDebited>) as event ->
      AccountDebited event.Data
  | _ -> failwith "Unknown Event"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get away with the amount of match cases you have, since you have to account for each case and this is the only way to do it when needing to downcast to a specific type.

You can consolidate the record definitions like so:

```ml
open System

type AccountCreated =
    { Owner: string
      AccountId: Guid
      CreatedAt: DateTimeOffset
      StartingBalance: decimal }
  
type AccountInfo =
    { To: Guid
      From: Guid
      Description: string
      Time: DateTimeOffset
      Amount: decimal }
  
type AccountEvent =
    | AccountCreated of AccountCreated
    | AccountCredited of accountCredited: AccountInfo
    | AccountDebited of accountDebited: AccountInfo
```

`AccountInfo` could also be an anonymous record if it's not useful to construct them outside the context of `AccountEvent`.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if it’s that bad at all because everything is explicit now.